# How to: Dynamically invoke javascript from asp.net input box?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, google-visualization

I have a asp.net input box:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="InCL" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
```

As soon as a number is entered I would like to send that value to a javascript function that updates a google gauge.

For example, user inputs 77, the [google gauge](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/gauge.html) immediately dynamically moves to that position.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank You.

**EDIT**
I'm looking at the onkeyup DOM event, is this a good way to go?

I think I'm just talking to myself on here.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a script in jQuery I used to do something very similar. It does indeed use `onkeyup` to set the value; it also uses `onkeydown` to prevent non-numeric values; and forces a default value of `0` if the user tries to leave the textbox with no value:

```
var updateUI = function(value) {
    //set gauge
};

var textbox = $('#id_of_textbox)'

textbox.keydown(function(e) {
    return validNumberKeys.indexOf(e.which) > -1;
}).keyup(function(e) {
    var input = $(e.target);
    if(input.val() !== '') {
        updateUI(input.val());
    }
}).blur(function(e) {
    var input = $(e.target);
    if(input.val()==='') { input.val('0'); }
    updateUI(input.val());
});

var validNumberKeys = [8,9,13,16,17,18,35,36,37,38,39,40,45,46,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="InCL" runat="server" onchange="YourJavaScriptFunction()" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
```

YourJavaScriptFunction() would then read the value out of InCL and do whatever you need to do with it.

You could also pass the value to your JavaScript like this: onchange="YourJavaScriptFunction(this.value)"

The same syntax will work with onkeyup: onkeyup="YourJavaScriptFunction()"

Comment: PS One problem with OnKeyUp is that it won't work if the user pastes a value into the TextBox